# New to C/C++ Using Android NDK to port Legacy code, getting compile errors

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I have been trying to take some old Symbian C++ code over to Android today using the NDK.

I have little to no C or C++ knowledge so its been a chore, however has to be done.

My main issue is that I'm having trouble porting what I believe is Symbian specifi code to work using the small C/C++ subset that is available with the Android NDK.

Here is a picture of the compilation errors I'm getting using cygwin

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to deal with these errors? For instance is TBool/Int/TUint/RPointerArray/RSocket a Symbian primitive and thats why it wont compile or is it something else?

Also what is ISO C++?

Any tutorials, guides or tips and help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a code snippet from the .h file I am trying to import followed by the output for the snippet from the compiler.

Could someone guide me on how I would port this Symbian specific code to normal C++?

If I got an idea of whats Symbian specific and how to change it I believe I could change then begin to port the rest myself

---

```
#ifndef __RTPSTREAM_H__
#define __RTPSTREAM_H__


class CRTPParser;

class MDataRecorderObserver
{
public:
virtual void DataRecorded(const TDesC8& aData, TUint aCodec, TUint aFramesizeMs)=0;

};

class MRTPStreamDataObserver
{
 public:
virtual void AudioDataSent()=0;
virtual void DataReceived(const TDesC8& aData,TUint aCodec, TBool aMarker, TUint aSeq, TUint aTime)=0;
virtual void DataReceived(const TDesC8& aData)=0;
};
```

---

```
$ make APP=ndk-socket
Android NDK: Building for application 'ndk-socket'
Compile++ thumb: socket <= apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtpstream.cpp
In file included from apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/com_ciceronetworks_utils_RTPJn
i.h:2,
             from apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtpstream.cpp:4:
build/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:489: note: the mangling of
'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
In file included from apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtpstream.cpp:11:
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declarati
on of 'TDesC8' with no type
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:15: error: expected ',' or '...' bef
ore '&' token
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declarati
on of 'TDesC8' with no type
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:23: error: expected ',' or '...' bef
ore '&' token
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:24: error: ISO C++ forbids declarati
on of 'TDesC8' with no type
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:24: error: expected ',' or '...' bef
ore '&' token
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:24: error: 'virtual void MRTPStreamD
ataObserver::DataReceived(int)' cannot be overloaded
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:23: error: with 'virtual void MRTPSt
reamDataObserver::DataReceived(int)'
apps/ndk-socket/project/jni/rtp/RTPStream.h:30: error: 'TInt' has not been deca
red
```

Comment: Yes those are all non standard types.. You're code appears to be full of Symbian specific code. Not sure what your code does, is it business logic? some algorithm implementation? User Interface? For ISO C++ read the wiki article on C++ 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_plus_plus.

Comment: As a note, you can copy text from a Windows command-prompt window by selecting "Edit -> Mark" from the menu you get by clicking on the little "c:" icon at the left end of the menu bar (or by hitting alt-space), selecting the text you want to copy with the mouse, and then hitting "enter" to copy it.  Much easier to read than a screencap, and you can then select bits of it to Google-search on.

Comment: Hi ivan, the code is an rtp stream implementation, Brooks, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Added Code snippet and compiler output for that peice of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "ISO C++", the G++ compiler means "The C++ standard".

This looks like the usual G++ error spew when it gets confused.  Typically only the top error message is meaningful, and then the rest is what the compiler prints out because it was confused.  The odd thing is that the initial error about "expected class name before '<' token" is itself more typical of error spew than real errors.  It's perhaps useful to have a look at that point in the code and see what it says and whether there's anything strange or compiler-specific there.

Also, from a Google-search, it looks like the initial note about va_name mangling is just informative and very unlikely to cause a problem in this case -- and, specifically, is certainly not going to cause the rest of these compiler errors.

**Edit:** Based on the revised error output and source code that you posted, it looks like the error is simply that this code is using the "TDesc8" data type without it first being declared, and the rest is likely to be followon from that.  According to the information I could find online [in the Symbian documentation](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Kernel_Architecture_2/TDesC8Class.html), code that uses that type should have a `#include <e32des8.h>` line to include the relevant header.  Does the code you are compiling include that header?

Comment: Thanks Brooks, I google searched the va_name mangling warning myself and came to that conclusion too, Sorry I should have posted that in my initial question. I have added a code snippet and the output from trying to compile that to see if anyone can make more sense of the issue

Comment: Donal: I've added an edit to my comment addressing the new information; hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Brooks, it would appear to be something like that, my code does not include that header as its not part of the build environment in the Android NDK, so it means that the Symbian code will need a complete rewrite by the looks of things